# Setting proxy in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, proxy, applet

the following is the code for setting proxy on server side.

```
# System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "220.134.110.231");  
# System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

I want to achieve the same thing on clint side.  Means the people visit my webpage (it will contain some javascript/applet). So my applet /javascript code should do this work for me
means whatever data the JavaScript /applet is trying to download should go through a proxy.

Comment: Don't think JS in a page can change browser's proxy settings.

Comment: You can't change the browser's proxy from javascript (at least not without a plugin).  What is it that you're trying to achieve?  There might be some other way to do it...

Comment: @jdigital : I dont want to change the browsers proxy settings. I want to use this proxy setting only for that request from that page made via ajav calls or a video player

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to do that with `javascript` alone.

If browsers allowed that behavior you'd only need to visit a compromised page to have a proxy set without your consent. Think instant tracking and a huge can of security worms.

**What you would need to do, is rethink your approach.**

Why does it need to download the video/flash/whatever through a proxy? May be you need is not a `http proxy`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: bold part sounds like Obi said: "you want to go home and rethink your life" :-). There it was appropriate and funny