# change browser http proxy settings dynamically

Tags: javascript, http, https

i want to redirect the URL (when user clicks any link in my web page) to another web server which is running on another machine through http proxy.is it possible to do via any script.

**EDIT**

Or is there any other way to do this like adding PAC(proxy auto configuration)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269045/setting-proxy-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

Luckily that is not possible. Otherwise I would (as the malicious person I am) redirect the client to my malicious pages filled with malware, viruses, keyloggers, logic bombs, etc using my malicious proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change users browser settings by JavaScript from a web page. That way a web page could set a bad proxy which then could spy and manipulate the users traffic.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible - luckily! See @RepWhoringPeeHaa's answer for some reasons.

However, if the user has firefox and the FoxyProxy extension installed you can use [its API](http://getfoxyproxy.org/developers/api.html) to make such changes.
Obviously the user needs to allow the site to make changes (similar dialog like when a new site wants to ask you for permission to install an extension).

Comment: or Is there any other way to do this like adding PAC(proxy auto configuration) .....

Comment: If the user enables the PAC file manually then yes. You cannot set it *for* him though.

Comment: Is it possible to add PAC file dynamically?.